# ¿Como puedo poner un elemento al lado de un input en boostrap?

Tags: bootstrap-3

Mi problema es de tipo front end.

Ya que lo unico que quiero hacer es que  mi etiqueta de tipo `<a>` se pueda poner justo al lado de mi input.

Codigo actual

```
    <div class="input-group pull-left">
        <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">@</span>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtBusquedaG" placeholder="Ingrse una busqueda" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
    </div>

    <a>¿Eres Artesano?</a>
```

El resultado es el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Deberas colocar tu CSS o probar meter <a>¿Eres Artesano?</a> dentro del div

Comment: Hola David, ¿podrías añadir algo más de contexto al código? También ¿qué es exactamente lo que quieres que se vea al lado? ¿El texto que pone "¿Eres Artesano?"? Lee [ask] y cómo crear un [mcve] para información y sugerencias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

aqui la cuestion es el row que se utiliza para el sistema de grillas deberias ver un tutorial de este sistema de bootstrap puedes acomodar hasta 12 elementos 
**class="col-md-4** aqui le estoy dando 4 pero puedes llegar hasta maximo de 12

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4>elemento1</div>
<div class="col-md-4>elemento2</div>
<div class="col-md-4>elemento3</div>
<div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <div class="row">  
                <div class="col-md-4">
                  <div class="input-group pull-left">
                      <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">@</span>
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtBusquedaG" placeholder="Ingrse una busqueda" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-1">  
                  <a>¿Eres Artesano?</a>
                </div>
                </div>  
              </div>
```

espero te sirva

Comment: Hola Carlos Enrique, las publicaciones que son sólo código se consideran de baja calidad. Por favor, añade al menos una pequeña descripción de los cambios que sugieres y cómo solucionarían el problema planteado en la pregunta. Lee [answer] para más información y recomendaciones.